# kubernetes queued worker with autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

- I have a job queue in sqs/rabbitMQ that has messages arriving infrequently
- Each time a message arrives in the queue I would like to spin up a new pod in my kubernetes cluster
- All pods will have the exact same configuration, they just perform operations on different data depending on what information they pull out of the queue
- When a pod spins up it will need to run for several hours and then can exit.
- If a pod fails it will need to restart and ideally read the same message from the queue that it orignally read
- There may be times when the message queue is totally empty and all pods have completed. But when a new message arrives in the queue it still needs to spawn a new pod
- Can anyone tell me if there are any design patterns for this kind of thing? Or should I be writing a script to manage my pods programatically?
- I'm open to any suggestions for any version of kubernetes including aws eks
- I've read through some of the design patterns [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-patterns) but they don't seem to fit my use case because

  a. **Queue with Pod Per Work Item**

  ```
   1. Doesn't seem to support jobs that don't complete after a pre-determined number of job completions
  ```

  b. **Queue with Variable Pod Count**

  ```
   2. Will not spawn new jobs after the first job completes. So it's not long running
  ```

Comment: Are you looking for something like knative eventing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just reading through the docs for knative eventing now. Can you suggest a workflow or a good starting point/any examples?

Answer (score 0):

The currents Job is, in my opinion, lacking for that sort of usage.
However, you can build a controller without too much trouble, if your messages (in the queue) have a reliable ID.

The idea would basically be :

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
tasks=$(get list of messages ID)
do
for task in tasks
do
   kubectl apply -f task-consumer-def.yaml -l task_id=$task
done
sleep 60
done
```

In `task-consumer-def.yaml`, you'd use the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) (which allows you to expose Pod information to the containers inside it) to expose the task id on which this worker needs to operate.

It's probably a better idea to use a `Job` in `task-consumer-def`, which will take care of the restarting part for you.

This is the operator pattern. Basically, you ensure that each message has a worker assigned to it. I think you can let Kubernetes handle the garbage collection of completed works items. If the message has already a pod assigned, it won't be changed.

You could probably do it more efficiently, or add a maximum, but the concept stays mostly the same.

A variation on that would be to use [Indexed Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/indexed-parallel-processing-static/) with several work items per Job, but it would be a bit more complicated.